# Windows 8.1 does not show version

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, powershell

so I have installed Windows 8.1 and I can't even see it's "Version" exact, thus, hindering me from putting a license to it (see links I mentioned). 
First link shows it via system properties, the other one is using msinfo32.exe. The third one is using winver

[image: https://imgur.com/a/UyeQS]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/npAdy]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/6krj3]

The main reason I'm trying to locate it is to obvisouly activate it because I can't proceed to Windows and Features to turn-on some things there (Hyper-V). 
I have already used several options via cmd and powershell but it won't even work

> PS C:\Windows\system32> dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
>
> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Error: 0x800f080c
>
> Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown. A Windows feature name was
>   not recognized. Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the
>   feature in the image and tr y the command again.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.

If someone has any ideas please let me know (just no advise of total re installation of OS). I got the ISO by using Windows Creation Tool.
If you do have some commands I'll gladly try it. Thanks!

Edit #2: Will editing registry and putting OS Version as Professional might fix it? I haven't tried it as it might somehow make the situation worst.

Comment: You are clearly running Windows 8.1 which is also known unofficially as Windows 8.1 Core.

Comment: Ohh, thank you for clarifying that, I've totally got no idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running “home” edition which is not what it’s called. It’s simply called Windows 8.1.

If it is professional or enterprise it will say “Windows 8.1 Professional” or “Windows 8.1 Enterprise”

http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-8/the-5-versions-of-windows-8-1/

Hyper-v is not available at all on the base edition of Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :) I've decided to give it a shot again and install windows 8.1 PRO, I think I accidentally used Windows 8.1. I checked the license (temporary license assigned), it's ending matches the generic key of  Windows 8.1 Core, not sure why that version didn't even come-up. So I've decided to install RSAT, and yeah, you're right, I can't even install it, which means I'm using really HOME Edition. Thank you :)